# Dimension of a Polytope

Tags: affine-geometry, polytopes

I am currently working on Regular Convex Polytopes and I don't know how to prove this statement:

"A polytope P is *k-dimensional*, if its affine hull is *k-dimensional*."

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What is your definition of the dimension of a polytope?

Comment: Are you sure this statement isn't just the *definition* of the dimension of a polytope, as opposed to a statement needing proof?

Comment: Yep, actually that is the part I'm not sure of. If it's just a definition, then done. At first, I think this is the definition but I again I'm not sure. Thank you guys.

Comment: Rockalellar's *Convex Analysis* (on p.12) uses this as the definition of the dimension of a convex set.  So maybe your sources do, too.

Comment: Thank you for your help.